# What is a standard or conventional name for a column representing display order?

Tags: schema, naming-convention

For example, a junction table associating a product and its pictures:

```
create table product_picture (
  product_id bigint not null references product(id),
  picture_id bigint not null references picture(id),
  some_column int not null
);
```

What is a common/conventional, short, general, name for `some_column` if it represents the display order of the photos?

`order`, `sort`, and `sequence` are out, as they are keywords.

Comment: `picture_ordinal`??  That's probably what I'd go with, but this is personal preference.

Comment: I usually use `sort_order` or `display_sequence`

Comment: Probably your RDBMS will allow you to still call it `order` if quoted. I just choose the most appropriate column name and if that happens to be a reserved word quote it.

Comment: Ordinal. At least in C# it is the same term used for the running number of fields in the returned data reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either "display_order" or "web_display_order", unless you have some hidden requirements.  (If you support multiple applications, and each has different display requirements, [application]_display_order makes sense.)

The important part can be abbreviated with "disp" and "ord" in English, as "disp_ord" or "web_disp_ord".

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what your philosophy is around column naming.

If you go for very descriptive long column names, then `display_order` is perfectly fine, since that is exactly what your column contains.

If you are comfortable with shorter names that may seem a little cryptic, but which can be figured out pretty easily, then you could use `seq` or `ord`.  For English speakers, `seq` is pretty unambiguous as there aren't a lot of words that this could reasonably represent.  I would pick that over `ord` for that reason.